# accessing a contract programmatically

Tags: racket

Is there a way to programmatically go through a contract? I went through [this page](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/contract-utilities.html) and seems like the only way to do so is to dump the contents out using `contract-name` as a list of datums?

Example: given `(-> number? string? number?)` how can I get the argument types? Was hoping there is something like `arg-types` that would return `'(number? string?)`. Likewise with the return type. Thanks!

Comment: No. Contracts can be written using arbitrary predicates (also nameless ones).